# Twig don't accept a <p> inside a <p>

Tags: html, twig, textile

I have just added a new *Twig* filter that give me HTML from a *Textile Markup*; so I return it **raw**.

It's embedded into a html paragraph and the *.twig* file look like this:

```
[..]
<p class="description">
    {{ description|textile|raw }}
</p>
[..]
```

**Description variable** contains another paragraph:

Some text

But the rendered content is this instead:

```
<p class="description"></p>
<p>
  Some text
</p>
```

and the variable is rendered outside of the container, with no apparent reason.

If I change the container to  it works perfectly

```
<div class="description">
    <p>
        Some text
    </p>
</div>
```

Someone can give me some reason?

Comment: Paragraph tags are not allowed inside of other paragraph tags. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1

Comment: Just so you know: Twig isn't doing this, your browser is. If you look at the actual source code instead of in a debugger it should show your nested paragraphs.

Comment: @WesleyMurch you are totally right! Just didn't know that the debugger could show a different source respect to the original one.
Thanks for linking to the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal, because `<p>` elements are not allowed inside other `<p>` elements.

Technically, the content model of [`<p>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) elements is [phrasing content](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#phrasing-content), which doesn't include other `<p>` elements.

You can validate your markup in http://validator.w3.org/